# WP_Query is only looping home page, not pages

Tags: loop, pages, homepage

So I am writing a wordpress loop and I want my loop to call the latest fifteen Pages (Not using any post whats so ever and its not an option) then I am looping through the LI tag and Span tag to populate the thumbnail. If your confused check it out xxlbreakcomp.com

My loop works, but its only calling my homepage info.I think I either need to write a second loop or an output but I have done both and neither works.I kinda just need a push in the right direction but I am totally lost.Plus the post__in array isn't working either.

```
            <div id="video-thumbs">

                  <ul id="selected">    

            <?php

            $query_args = array (
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                    'order' => 'DESC',  
                    'post_per_page' => 15, 
                    'post_type' => 'page',
                    'post__in'=> array       (4,7,8,9,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25)
                ); 

            $query = new WP_Query($query_args);

            if ( $query->have_posts() ) :       

                while ( $query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

                    wp_reset_postdata ();

                    ?>
                      <li data-permalink="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="selected">
                      <span style= "background: url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/library/images/thumb_pic.png')"></span>
                      <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                endwhile;
            endif;

            ?>

            <?php wp_reset_postdata (); // reset the query ?>

            </ul>

            </div>
```

Comment: Try removing the first "wp_reset_postdata ();"

Comment: @DavidKryzaniak it worked!! That only took 5 secs to erase and 6 hours of googling. *Virtual Hug*, Thank you.

Comment: @DavidKryzaniak -- You should post your comment as a solution, so that Abi can accept it, and this question can be marked as resolved. (Plus you get more [whuffie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whuffie) that way.)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure if it was going to be this easy to solve. :)

Comment: No apology necessary. Sometimes the easy solutions are the hardest ones to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the first "wp_reset_postdata ();" solved the problem.